# How to host our Portfolio in Github pages?

Tags: github, html5-canvas, github-pages, portfolio

I have created the portfolio website using HTML5 and uploaded the respective files in the GitHub with new repository, but I cannot able to view the url link like (it is published at...) shown in YouTube videos.

I searched GitHub pages under the "`Code and Automation`" tab, still I cannot able to view the URL.

Can somebody please help me where to view my portfolio?

Comment: IIRC your repository must be called `<YourGHUserName>.github.io` AND must be public AND you must publish `index.html` + artefacts to the master branch, OR if your repo name is not `<YourGHUserName>.github.io`, then you must create a `gh-pages` branch AND the repo must be public AND you must publish `index.html` + artefacts to the `gh-pages` branch. Also double check that you have enabled GitHub pages in the settings. For more information, check out the GitHub Pages tutorial: https://pages.github.com/

Answer (score 0):

Note: [GitHub Pages now uses Actions by default](https://github.blog/2022-08-10-github-pages-now-uses-actions-by-default/)

It means that, instead of configuring a [publication source](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site) (a branch or `docs/` folder), you can add in a [`.github/workflows`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/understanding-github-actions#workflows) (inside your repository) a [`actions/starter-workflows` `pages/static.yml`](https://github.com/actions/starter-workflows/blob/main/pages/static.yml) in order to publish your static HTML5 pages.